# What is the radial quantum number $n_r$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, terminology, definition

As we know, the principal quantum number  $ n=1,2,3,... $  is related to the radial quantum number  $ n_r=0,1,2,... $  by  $$  n=n_r+\ell+1 .$$
What is the physical (or chemical) definition of the radial quantum number $n_r$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement @EmilioPisanty's answer: the importance of $n_r$ and the number of nodes is that, for *fixed* $L$, the energy increases with $n_r$.  The restriction to fixed $L$ comes because, for a given potential, the energy increases with $n_r$.  Here, the potential is the *effective potential* which contains the centrifugal barrier $\sim \ell(\ell+1)/r^2$ terms.  The increase with $n_r$ is a general feature of the solutions of the Schrodinger equation, and the centrifugal term is present in every spherically-symmetric potential.

Since $n=n_r+\ell+1$, it is clear that increasing $n_r$ increases $n$ and thus increases the energy.  Examples below illustrate the probability densities as a function of $r$ for $\ell=0$ and $\ell=2$ states, and also show that increasing $n_r$ correspond to increasing $n$ and thus to increasing energy.  Note how the scale of the horizontal axis (the $r$ axis) changes with $n$ because the tail of the hydrogen solutions are of the form $e^{-r/(2n a_0)}$ so that larger $n$ solutions extend well beyond smaller $n$ solutions.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The radial quantum number counts the number of radial nodes in the wavefunction:

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hydrogen_Density_Plots.png)</sup>